# MYSQL 8.0.23-cloud left join on information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE is not working

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, rdbms, information-schema

I imported [sakila-schema.sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html) to MYSQL 8.0.23-cloud. I am trying to get constraint name of the column which is part a foreign key.
requiredConstraintName column in second output row is coming wrong. It should come 'Primary' but coming 'NULL'. I tried same query with MYSQL 8.0.17, output was coming correct.
Can anybody help to get this solved?

```html
-- Query
select * from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where table_name='customer';

-- Output
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION,POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
def,sakila,PRIMARY,def,sakila,customer,customer_id,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
def,sakila,fk_customer_address,def,sakila,customer,address_id,1,1,sakila,address,address_id
def,sakila,fk_customer_store,def,sakila,customer,store_id,1,1,sakila,store,store_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Query
select * from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where table_name='store';

-- Output
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION,POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
def,sakila,idx_unique_manager,def,sakila,store,manager_staff_id,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
def,sakila,PRIMARY,def,sakila,store,store_id,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
def,sakila,fk_store_address,def,sakila,store,address_id,1,1,sakila,address,address_id
def,sakila,fk_store_staff,def,sakila,store,manager_staff_id,1,1,sakila,staff,staff_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Problem Query
SELECT
    a.*,
    a_rf.constraint_name as requiredConstraintName
FROM
    information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE a
        left JOIN
    information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE a_rf
    ON a_rf.TABLE_SCHEMA = a.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND a_rf.TABLE_NAME = a.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
        AND a_rf.COLUMN_NAME = a.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
where a.table_name = 'customer'
ORDER BY a.TABLE_NAME , a.CONSTRAINT_NAME , a.ORDINAL_POSITION;

-- Output
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION,POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT,REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,requiredConstraintName
def,sakila,fk_customer_address,def,sakila,customer,address_id,1,1,sakila,address,address_id,PRIMARY
def,sakila,fk_customer_store,def,sakila,customer,store_id,1,1,sakila,store,store_id,NULL
def,sakila,PRIMARY,def,sakila,customer,customer_id,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue, were you able to identify the problem?